# Search of an object in Database tool in DataGrip

Tags: datagrip

I'm new to DataGrip. There is a database in `Database tool`, it has a lot of schemas, tables and views, etc. When I open DataGrip all folders are collapsed.

[image: Database tool in DataGrip]

I start typing to make some filtering to find my table among the hundred of another objects. In this case it finds nothing.

[image: Filtering fails]

But if I expand the schema "folder" and the tables "folder" if it's visible filtering works correctly.

[image]

Is there a way to filter in collapsed 'folders'? I just know the name of the object but I don't even know if it is a table or SP or a View.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no possibility to filter in collapsed folders. But, there are several ways which can help you in your task.

1. **Go to object** action. Press Cmd+O and type the name of the object. If it is a table, a data editor will open. To see the DDL of the table, then press the DDL button on the top panel in data editor.
   [image]
   If you wish to see the object in the database tree as well, use Auto-scroll from editor option.
   [image]
2. Second way: you can expand the whole tree. To do that, press Cmd+Shift+A (Find Action). And type 'Expand tree'. After that filtering will go through all the objects. But I think the first way is better.

PS. If you're new to DataGrip, this page can help you to understand the product better: https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/features/